# Finding solution of non-homogeneous linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, homogeneous-equation

> Find the solution to the non-homogeneous linear system below.
>   $$\begin{aligned}-x_1 - x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 &= 2\\-x_1 - x_2 + 2x_3     - x_5 &= 4\\-x_1 - x_2 + 2x_3 &= 5\\-x_1 - x_2 + 2x_4 + 4x_5 &= 1\end{aligned}$$
>
> Write your solution using parameters $s$, $t$, etc. For example
>
> $\text{sol}=x_\text{part}+\text{sol}_\text{hom}={(1,2,3,4,5)+s(1,0,0,0,0)+t(0,1,0,0,0)}$

So, I have this question to solve but, it takes so much time for me to solve these kinds of problems is there any way to solve it much faster, if there is can you show me please.

Comment: Please show where you got stuck and what takes so much time. You just have to do the elimination. What are the solutions for the homogenous system?

Comment: I believe that this question is meant to be straightforward. What techniques do you have at your disposal? There is an obvious method you should by all means use if you know it.

Comment: You can sometimes take shortcuts if you can spot useful relationships among the equations. For instance, the second and third equations differ by only one term, so you can solve for one of the variables immediately. All of the equations have $-x_1-x_2$, so you might be able to use that to your advantage as well. In general, though, you’ll just have to grind it out using whatever is in your toolkit. You’ll get faster with practice.

Comment: I usually try to find the answer by finding x1 or x2 till x5 but in this one, I couldn't find the answer no matter how many times I tried. If there is no other way can someone help me to find the solution to this question please.

Comment: Have you tried good old-fashioned Gaussian elimination?